# Share request-specific object from custom authentication filter to controllers / models

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, c#-5.0

My API's custom authentication populates an entity from the database. How can I share this request-specific object ('mapping' in the case below) with my controllers so that I do not have to query the database twice for the same info?

```
public class CustomAuth : Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter, IDisposable
{
    public async Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken){
      var query = _readEntities.Query<API_Exe_Mapping>();
      var mapping = await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync(...);
      ...
}
```

Comment: Do you need to use the data to be loaded into your CustomAuth and cleaned at the end of the request ? Of course you will access to that data in the controller action.

Comment: Yes how do I access the data loaded in customauth in my controller. I do not need to clean it. It is an object, not a username

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using HttpRequestMessage.Properties**

You can use the `HttpRequesteMessage.Properties` property like this:

```
public async Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // your code here 
    context.Request.Properties["MyDataKey"] = new List<string> { "from my properties" };
}
```

Then in your controller you just you just use the following code :

```
var data = this.ActionContext.Request.Properties["MyDataKey"];
```

The collection is cleaned for each http request.

**Using HttpContext.Current.Items**

You can use one the following solution and it will use the static property `HttpContext.Current.Items`

```
public async Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // your code here 
    HttpContext.Current.Items["MyDataKey"] = new List<string> { "from my items" };
}
```

Then in your controller you just check the same dictionary collection `HttpContext.Current.Items` and retrieve the data by using the same key. `Items` collection will be cleaned when the http request is terminated.